# np.fromfunction: Reference other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create an array based on whether values in one array are in another array. I was hoping the following would work:

```
A = np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: tuple(order[x,:]) in paths[y,],\
    shape=((len(order), len(paths))), dtype=int)
```

Unfortunately, this only yield a scalar value and not the array I want. I can achieve the same with a for loop as follows, but this option is very slow due to the number of values involved.

```
A = np.zeros(shape=(len(order), len(paths)), dtype=int)
for i in np.ndindex(len(order), len(paths)):
    r = i[0] # Row
    c = i[1] # Column
    x = r + c + (len(paths)-1)*r
    if paths[c,] == None:
        pass
    elif tuple(order[r,:]) in paths[c,]:
        np.put(A, x, 1, 'wrap')
```

Does anyone have an efficient way to generate the target matrix? Thanks a lot for your help!

\edit: Thanks a lot for your tips hpaulj. I think `np.where` goes into the direction of what I want to achieve, but can't handle the complexity of the two array. I edited the approach above, as `x = r*c if r*c != 0 else r+c` didn't give me the results I wanted - which I somehow figured out when my output was gibberish... `x = r + c + (len(paths)-1)*r` does however work in uniquely identifying each position of the flattend 2D array. I included samples below which should make it clearer of what I'm trying to achieve. Sorry for the confusion!

```
order
[[ 73   6   3   1]
 [ 73   6   3   2]
 [  6 116   3   1]
 [  6 116   3   2]
 [116  45   3   1]
 ...10k additional lines...]

paths
[ [(12, 14, 1615, 1), (14, 156, 1615, 1), (156, 83, 1615, 1), (83, 37, 1554, 1), (37, 36, 1554, 1)]
  [(12, 14, 1615, 2), (14, 156, 1615, 2), (156, 83, 1615, 2), (83, 37, 1554, 2), (37, 36, 1554, 2)]
  [(12, 14, 1615, 1), (14, 156, 1615, 1), (156, 83, 1615, 1), (83, 37, 1554, 1), (37, 36, 1554, 1)]
  [(12, 14, 1615, 2), (14, 156, 1615, 2), (156, 83, 1615, 2), (83, 37, 1554, 2), (37, 36, 1554, 2)]
  [(12, 14, 1615, 1), (14, 156, 1615, 1), (156, 83, 1615, 1), (83, 37, 1554, 1), (37, 36, 1554, 1)]
  [(12, 14, 1615, 2), (14, 156, 1615, 2), (156, 83, 1615, 2), (83, 37, 1554, 2), (37, 36, 1554, 2)]
  ...600 additional lines...]
```

The goal is to check whether each value of `order` is within `paths` and of it is put a `True` or `1` in the row/column intersection. All other intersections should be `False`/`0`. Maintaining the order of rows and columns is critical as the matrix is then multiplied with an ordered vector. Effectively I am working on a simulation of this (URL - see below, p94) algorithm. The matrix is supposed to reflect the utilisation of a specific resource (`order`) by a specific product (`paths`).

URL: https://books.google.com/books?id=GhdDbEM-_5oC&lpg=PA100&ots=wH5OVDz7JV&dq=dlp%20revenue%20management&pg=PA94#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the code form `fromfunction`.

```
args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
return function(*args,**kwargs)
```

`np.indices` is like `meshgrid`

```
In [28]: np.indices((2,3))
Out[28]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

So `np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i + j, (3, 3), dtype=int)` is the equivalent of doing

```
In [29]: idn=np.indices((2,3))
In [31]: idn[0]+idn[1]
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Which I'd normally do with broadcasting: `np.arange(2)[:,None] + np.arange(3)`

There is a `np.frompyfunc` which will apply a Python function to each element of its input.  But it only works with 1d (though there are some neat tricks around that with structured arrays).  `np.vectorize` uses this as well.  But both still iterate, so the time savings are at most 2x.

===============

`ndindex` is another way of generating index values

```
In [42]: list(np.ndindex(2,3))
Out[42]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]

In [43]: list(zip(*np.ndindex(2,3)))
Out[43]: [(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)]
```

With the `zip` transpose I get values similar to those produced by `nd.indices` (but raveled).

======================

Without sample values for `order` and `paths` it is hard to imagine what your function is doing.  Or rather, just from reading the code I can't picture what it is doing, and without the samples I can't run a test.  For a 'blackbox' function that takes scalar `i,j` coordinates, your approach is about as good as it gets.  To make it fast, you have to rework the function so it uses uses the subarrays of `np.indices` directly, not iteratively.

===============

A vectorized approach to getting your `x` value could be

```
In [105]: I,J=np.indices((3,3))

In [106]: np.where(I*J,I*J,I+J)
Out[106]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 4]])
```

The `where` performs the `x = r*c if r*c != 0 else r+c` on a whole array.

The same thing with boolean masking (a good tool for array `if` tests) is:

```
In [114]: x=I*J

In [115]: mask = x==0

In [116]: x[mask]=(I+J)[mask]

In [117]: x
Out[117]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 4]])
```